# Rotating buffered image in Java

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I have written a method for image rotation in Java (allowed rotations are 90, 180 and 270 degrees), but it seems that it is not working as it should. I am clearly doing something wrong but I am completely unable to figure out what. The problem about the output is that the image is indeed rotated, but there are black pieces of the image, like if an image is not in the correct place.

My first attempt was to do it without result variable that I use as a destination, instead, I did this:

```
return affineTransformOp.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```

And rotation was good, no black parts of images, but the color was weird like if some colors were changed, skin color became red. So I have changed it when I saw that someone else had the same problem.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
private BufferedImage rotateImage(ImageData imageData, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();

    affineTransform.rotate(imageData.getRotation().getRotationAngle(), bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);

    AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getHeight(), bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getType());

    affineTransformOp.filter(bufferedImage, result);

    return result;
}
```

I have also tried translating the image, but it didn't help much.

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer if someone in the future has the same problem.

This is modified Java method that solved my problem:

```
private BufferedImage rotateImage(ImageRotation imageRotation, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();

    if (ImageRotation.ROTATION_90.equals(imageRotation) || ImageRotation.ROTATION_270.equals(imageRotation)) {
        affineTransform.translate(bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2, bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2);
        affineTransform.rotate(imageRotation.getRotationAngle());
        affineTransform.translate(-bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, -bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);

    } else if (ImageRotation.ROTATION_180.equals(imageRotation)) {
        affineTransform.translate(bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);
        affineTransform.rotate(imageRotation.getRotationAngle());
        affineTransform.translate(-bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, -bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);

    } else {
        affineTransform.rotate(imageRotation.getRotationAngle());
    }

    AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    BufferedImage result;

    if (ImageRotation.ROTATION_90.equals(imageRotation) || ImageRotation.ROTATION_270.equals(imageRotation)) {
        result = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getHeight(), bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getType());

    } else {
        result = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), bufferedImage.getType());
    }

    affineTransformOp.filter(bufferedImage, result);

    return result;
}
```